# Which "geom_" to use to draw a bar/line for each observation starting from the x-axis?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

My goal is to draw a plot with, for each observation, a vertical bar of small width connecting the point to the y=0 line (the x-axis).

I tried different geoms my understanding is that `geom_bar` would not work because it can only take positive values but I am not really sure. The closest to what I want is `geom_step` but it is still not really what I expected. Do you know a way to do it ?

An example of a plot I like is here:

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0lyY.png)

But my points are not regularly spaced on the x-axis so it is even more difficult.
If you need a concrete exemple you can use this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(5.23, 5.67, 6, 9, 15, 15.2),
                 y=c(2, 4, -2, -1, 1, -9))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the data slightly by repeating each x-value with y set to zero.  This way we can group by x-value and draw a line with a big enough width to represent a bar.  After this adjustment, you should be able to use `geom_step` or `geom_path` to draw a similar figure.

```
## Sample data
dat <- data.frame(x=(x=seq(0, 10, length=100)),
                  y=exp(0.3*x)*sin(1.5*x) + rnorm(100))

## Repeat each x-value, setting y to zero
dat <- rbind(dat, data.frame(x=dat$x, y=0))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_path(lwd=1.2, aes(group=x), color="steelblue") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks nongkrong exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 5):

If we borrow @nongkrong's `dat` you can do it even more simply with `geom_segment`:

```
gg <- ggplot(dat)
gg <- gg + geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=x, y=0, yend=y))
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg
```

[image]

If we use your `df` it's the same technique:

```
gg <- ggplot(df)
gg <- gg + geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=x, y=0, yend=y))
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg
```

[image]

Comment: I love both of your answer but if I had to choose the one of nongkrong is even more accurate and pretty. But thanks anyway !